# Is there a way to allow ad bots to crawl a website that has "noindex,nofollow" on it?

Tags: googlebot, web-crawlers, robots.txt, advertising, cpc-ads

Due to duplicated content, there is a "noindex,nofollow" on the website, but in order to run ppc ads, there needs to be a way for the ads bots to crawl the website

Can this be done without removing the noindex,nofollow tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Noindex` and `nofollow` aren't bot crawling directives, they are search engine indexing directives. Because they don't prevent crawling, I don't see why they would interact with ad bots.

I've found some forum posts that seem to corroborate that ad bots do not care about `noindex`:

> A lot of things can go wrong here, but yes, you can run ads to noindex pages.
>
> [Running ads on "noindex" pages - Webmaster World](https://www.webmasterworld.com/google_adwords/4969429.htm)

and

> Noindex should not be a problem as long as you've not blocked adsesebot from crawling the pages.
>
> [Adsense ads, on noindex pages? - Webmaster World](https://www.webmasterworld.com/google_adsense/4970469.htm)